# How to identify the Drive root folder

Tags: google-drive-api

I am having trouble identifying the root folder of a user's Drive. For English users it is named 'My Drive', however for French users it is named 'Mon Drive'. The file Id is unique for all root folders so this property can't be used.

How can I conclusively identify if the a folder is the root folder of the user's Drive only from the response from the [metadata api](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/get)?

Answer (score 1):

You may not have folders parent ID if someone shares folder with you that you did not add to your own drive yet. Basically 'Shared with Me' folders do't have a parent ID.

You can do a GET to get details of your root folder.

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/root
```

Remember to mention literally **root** at the end of this URL. This is alias of your root folder. You should get a JSOn response where you should have 'id' of root folder.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link to try: 
https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/get#try-it

[image]

I am providing an id of file, which is not in the root directory. Note: We can get the fileId from --> **right click file > get Shareable link >> there is id={***fileId***}**

I provided my fileId, it executed with below JSON output, where you can see `isRoot:false. /* It means that file holding directory is not root directory */`

**The output result in json format:**

```
{
 "kind": "drive#file",
 "id": "0B-loIMZmVFUXZXJDRjM5cjhhNmM",
 "etag": "\"ZAMbZ9abHBEg72qh6Q2B0zjcjMA/MTUwMDg3NzA3ODA0MQ\"",
 "selfLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/0B-loIMZmVFUXZXJDRjM5cjhhNmM",
 "webContentLink": "https://drive.google.com/uc?id=0B-loIMZmVFUXZXJDRjM5cjhhNmM&export=download",
 "alternateLink": "https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-loIMZmVFUXZXJDRjM5cjhhNmM/view?usp=drivesdk",
 "embedLink": "https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-loIMZmVFUXZXJDRjM5cjhhNmM/preview?usp=drivesdk",
 "iconLink": "https://drive-thirdparty.googleusercontent.com/16/type/video/mpeg",
 "thumbnailLink": "https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/1VGXZZ-keO9yO5P5eYkUWrKXNsi9dG80zGQHlSRr4usJn_AAWGL-prXhoSeBV_XwXKqzQQ=s220",
 "title": "VTS_01_1.VOB",
 "mimeType": "video/mpeg",
 "labels": {
  "starred": false,
  "hidden": false,
  "trashed": false,
  "restricted": false,
  "viewed": true
 },
 "createdDate": "2017-07-11T00:58:46.342Z",
 "modifiedDate": "2017-07-24T06:17:58.041Z",
 "modifiedByMeDate": "2017-07-24T06:17:58.041Z",
 "lastViewedByMeDate": "2017-07-24T06:18:20.076Z",
 "markedViewedByMeDate": "1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
 "version": "677073",
 "parents": [
  {
   "kind": "drive#parentReference",
   "id": "0B-loIMZmVFUXYjFpTnNpWXM5U0k",
   "selfLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/0B-loIMZmVFUXZXJDRjM5cjhhNmM/parents/0B-loIMZmVFUXYjFpTnNpWXM5U0k",
   "parentLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/0B-loIMZmVFUXYjFpTnNpWXM5U0k",
   "isRoot": false
  }
 ],
 "downloadUrl": "https://doc-0k-48-docs.googleusercontent.com/docs/securesc/bculidesqdf6868f2kpe9ck7n2ek7rik/tf0bp5qc9adb3l2nvq8224jlefl11mbl/1500876000000/00155113073667341356/00155113073667341356/0B-loIMZmVFUXZXJDRjM5cjhhNmM?e=download&gd=true",
 "userPermission": {
  "kind": "drive#permission",
  "etag": "\"ZAMbZ9abHBEg72qh6Q2B0zjcjMA/sYdDjsCbpl5sdrQ1oJnGyZ0gu5M\"",
  "id": "me",
  "selfLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/0B-loIMZmVFUXZXJDRjM5cjhhNmM/permissions/me",
  "role": "owner",
  "type": "user"
 },
 "originalFilename": "VTS_01_1.VOB",
 "fileExtension": "VOB",
 "md5Checksum": "5328c8049ca351743ac7f30af1c242f6",
 "fileSize": "389033984",
 "quotaBytesUsed": "389033984",
 "ownerNames": [
  "Uddhav Gautam"
 ],
 "owners": [
  {
   "kind": "drive#user",
   "displayName": "Uddhav Gautam",
   "picture": {
    "url": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-UoxeYRihw94/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAFBQ/GY5GOL_IGwU/s64/photo.jpg"
   },
   "isAuthenticatedUser": true,
   "permissionId": "00155113073667341356",
   "emailAddress": "infofuniversities@gmail.com"
  }
 ],
 "lastModifyingUserName": "Uddhav Gautam",
 "lastModifyingUser": {
  "kind": "drive#user",
  "displayName": "Uddhav Gautam",
  "picture": {
   "url": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-UoxeYRihw94/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAFBQ/GY5GOL_IGwU/s64/photo.jpg"
  },
  "isAuthenticatedUser": true,
  "permissionId": "00155113073667341356",
  "emailAddress": "infofuniversities@gmail.com"
 },
 "capabilities": {
  "canCopy": true,
  "canEdit": true
 },
 "editable": true,
 "copyable": true,
 "writersCanShare": true,
 "shared": true,
 "explicitlyTrashed": false,
 "appDataContents": false,
 "headRevisionId": "0B-loIMZmVFUXWmFnM0Q2YnpDaGphc0lPMXNNZ1JYc2JpdllBPQ",
 "videoMediaMetadata": {
  "width": 720,
  "height": 480,
  "durationMillis": "494631"
 },
 "spaces": [
  "drive"
 ]
}
```

If you want to know if a directory is root directory or not? You can simply use
 `if(yourDirectory.getParents().size() > 0) { /* your directory can't be root here. Root directory has no parent directory */ }`

Comment: This is regarding the Google Drive API